# Can I get lead Id on converted contact record? Is there any standard field on contact which shows lead id?

Tags: lead-conversion

I have set of Contact Ids thru which I have to find related lead Ids, I am planning to write SOQL query on contact to get lead Id but I am not sure whether salesforce provides any standard field on contact to show Lead Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a formula field on Lead called `Id18` and populate it with `CASESAFEID()`
- Then map this `Lead.Id18__c` field to a Contact custom field called `LeadId__c` (Text, len 18, external Id unique) in the Map Lead Fields rules

Then you can query the converted lead from the Contact:

```
   SELECT Id, ... FROM Lead
    WHERE Id = :myContact.LeadId__c
```

Answer (score 2):

It is other way round.

Salesforce provides `ConvertedContactId` field on `Lead` object which shows the ContactId generated after Lead Conversion.

You can create separate field like `LeadId` on Contact object and write a logic to populate that field during conversion.